# prove convergence to a limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

So im asked to prove that the function $a_{n}$ converges to a certain limit
$$
a_{n} = {{1+2+...+ \ n}\over{n^2}}
$$
So what I have so far is this:
$$
a_{n} = {{1+2+...+ \ n}\over{n^2}} = {n(n+1)\over2n^2}={1\over 2}+{1\over 2n}
\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}={1\over 2}
\\
\epsilon > 0 \ \ \ \exists \ \ \ N \ \ \ s.t \ \ \ \ n\ge N \ \ \Rightarrow |a_{n}-L| < \epsilon
\\
|{1\over2}+{1\over2n}-{1\over2}|={1\over2n}<\epsilon \Longleftrightarrow n>{1\over2\epsilon}
\\
$$
Is there anything wrong with this, im so confused as to what's right or wrong with this university math

Comment: i think, it is ok.

Comment: @user3258845 I find this to be okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that such $N$ exists?

Do this:

Given $\epsilon \gt 0$,

$|a_n - L| \lt \epsilon$ $\Leftarrow \Rightarrow$ $|\frac 12+ \frac 1{2n}- \frac 12|=\frac 1{2n} \lt \epsilon$ $\Leftarrow \Rightarrow$ $n \gt \frac {1}{2\epsilon}$.

By Using Archimedean property, we get $N \gt 0$ such that $n \ge N \gt \frac {1}{2\epsilon}$.

Comment: So is n the infinitely small sequence? Sorry, I never had this explained to me before.

Comment: To say that a sequence $(a_n)$ has limit $L$ is alternative to saying that for a given $\epsilon \gt 0$ we must find a natural number $N$ such that for $n \ge N$ we get $|a_n - L| \lt \epsilon$. In above question what we did was finding condition on $n$ (i.e. $n \gt \frac {1}{2\epsilon}$) and then Use Archimedean property to get $N$.

Comment: In simple non-rigorous words, $\epsilon$ is a distance between $a_n$ and $L$. Getting $N$ as above means after the $a_N$th term, all the next terms of the sequence $(a_n)$ would be inside the $\epsilon$ distance. If we don't get such $N$, then the sequence can not be said to be convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is fine, if a little rough around the edges. To "complete" your proof I suggest simply going through the definition of the limit, while keeping your scratch-work in mind:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$, now choose $N > \frac{1}{2\varepsilon}$ now for all $n \geq N$ we have
$$ \left|a_n - \frac{1}{2} \right| = \left|\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2}\right| = \frac{1}{2n} \leq \frac{1}{2N} \leq  \varepsilon$$
Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary this proves convergence.

If you are interested in an alternative proof, here is one with Riemann sums!

Note that
$$ \frac{1 + 2 + ... + n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n}$$
Now define $f(x) = x$. The limit may be written
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n} \right)$$
Which is the Riemann sum of the function $f(x)$ over the interval $[0,1]$ so we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n} \right) = \int_0^1 x \ dx = \frac{1}{2}$$
This proof is overkill because it assumes you are familiar with integration, but Riemann sums are a nice tool to use!